# How to push data into a JSON variable

Tags: javascript, json, push

I have a JSON variable which looks like this :

```
{"events": [
{"event_id": "1", "event_name": "Breakfast"},
{"event_id": "1", "event_name": "Calling Bob"}
]}
```

I need to push another attribute in each event with javascript and make it look like this:

```
{"events": [
{"event_id": "1", "event_name": "Breakfast", "event_type": "calendar"},
{"event_id": "1", "event_name": "Calling Bob", "event_type": "calendar"}
]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have

```
var obj = {"events": [....
```

then just use

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.events.length; ++i)
    obj.events[i].event_type = "calendar";
```

Or to optimise:

```
for (var i = 0, len = obj.events.length; i < len; ++i)
    obj.events[i].event_type = "calendar";
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to an `Object` first:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(theJSON);

for(var i = 0; i < obj.events.length; ++ i)
    obj.events[i].event_type = "calendar";

theJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: wtf are you doing? that has nothing to do with the OPs problem. Just push the entry into the array. No need to stringify/parse.

Comment: He explicitly said he had _JSON_ to work with, not a JS object.

Comment: @Christoph - This is exactly the OPs problem... he does not want to push another element into the array... read the question again. (+1, but consider changing to a normal `for` loop)

Comment: for-in iteration over an Array is error-prone, since you can inadvertently touch unrelated fields of the object (consider `var a = ["foo"]; a.myField = 3`: for-in will pick the "0" and "myField" fields).

Comment: this code is missing hasOwnProperty and introduces error-prone notation by leaving out the `{}`, -1 for me...

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Yes, I'm aware of that - not sure why I wrote it with for .. in to begin with. Edited.

Comment: Yes, looks much better now :)

Comment: well, i guess i didn't read the question good enough, my fault. add `{` and you get +1 from me since you're right...sry.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourJson = {"events": [
    {"event_id": "1", "event_name": "Breakfast"},
    {"event_id": "1", "event_name": "Calling Bob"}
]};

for(var eventKey in yourJson.events) {
    yourJson.events[eventKey]['event_type'] = 'calendar';
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment to James McLaughlin's answer for why for-in iteration over an Array is not recommended. Apart from being a bit slower than the usual indexed iteration.

Comment: thank you for the answer i have learned something new from it .. how to use that fancy for loop :)